# JOptionPane showConfirmDialog if else statement not working

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, joptionpane

No matter what I do the NO part never works,I've tried with another if,else if,else,brackets ,no brackets. It just prints hello no matter what i click.I want the system to exit if i press NO

```
import javax.swing.*;

class ok
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null,"Can you come at my house on 18th??" ," SERIOUS QUESTION",dialogButton,3);
        if (dialogButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HELLO");
        } else if (dialogButton == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
            System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not capturing the return value of `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog`

Comment: how do I do that?I am new to programming

Answer (score 1):

You're not capturing the return value of `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog`. Something like this:

```
class ok
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        int options = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Can you come at my house on 18th?" ,"SERIOUS QUESTION", options, 3);
        if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HELLO");
        } else if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            System.exit(0);
        } 
    }
}
```